# C# serialize generic list<customObject> to file

Tags: c#, serialization, generic-list

i got a class which holds info about pictures, like filepath, hashvalue, bytes.
in another class i got a generic list where i put objects from the class that holds picture info.

that class looks like this:

```
[Serializable()]
    class PicInfo : ISerializable
    {
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        public string completeFileName { get; set; }
        public string filePath { get; set; }
        public byte[] hashValue { get; set; }

        public PicInfo()
        { }

        public PicInfo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            this.fileName = (string)info.GetValue("fileName", typeof(string));
            this.completeFileName = (string)info.GetValue("completeFileName", typeof(string));
            this.filePath = (string)info.GetValue("filePath", typeof(string));
            this.hashValue = (byte[])info.GetValue("hashValue", typeof(byte[]));
        }

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            info.AddValue("fileName", this.fileName);
            info.AddValue("completeFileName", this.completeFileName);
            info.AddValue("filePath", this.filePath);
            info.AddValue("hashValue", this.hashValue);
        }
    }
```

my list is just `list<picinfo> pi = new list<picinfo>();`
what would be the eaziest way to serialize this list?

Comment: You should really clarify your question a bit more. What serialization format are you looking for? Human readable? Binary? More information please

Comment: It will work just fine without using ISerializable.  .NET can serialize it all for use easily enough..?

Comment: the format should be binary, sorry for not telling this.

Comment: @mtijn incorrect; that only applies to `XmlSerializer`

Comment: @Yustme if you are using `BinaryFormatter` (which I assume you are), it will be binary *whether or not* you implement `ISerializable`. I strongly suggest not implementing `ISerializable` unless you have good reason (but then: I also strongly suggest not using `BinaryFormatter` in the first place ;p)

Comment: well i dont see another option instead of binaryformatter, since i have to save a byte[] aswel.

Comment: @Yustme any serializer can write to a byte[] via MemoryStream...

Comment: @Yustme if I misunderstood your byte[] remark - almost every serializer will handle `byte[]` without issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to use `BinaryFormatter` (which I really don't advise), you can use:

```
[Serializable]
class PicInfo
{
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string completeFileName { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }
    public byte[] hashValue { get; set; }

    public PicInfo()  { }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<PicInfo> pi = new List<PicInfo>();
        pi.Add(new PicInfo {fileName = "foo.bar", hashValue = new byte[] {1, 2, 3}});

        var ser = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ser.Serialize(ms, pi);
            var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use `XmlSerializer` (probably preferable IMO), but need the `byte[]`, then:

```
public class PicInfo
{
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string completeFileName { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }
    public byte[] hashValue { get; set; }

    public PicInfo()  { }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<PicInfo> pi = new List<PicInfo>();
        pi.Add(new PicInfo {fileName = "foo.bar", hashValue = new byte[] {1, 2, 3}});

        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<PicInfo>));
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ser.Serialize(ms, pi);
            var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd use protobuf-net:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class PicInfo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]public string fileName { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]public string completeFileName { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]public string filePath { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4)]public byte[] hashValue { get; set; }

    public PicInfo()  { }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<PicInfo> pi = new List<PicInfo>();
        pi.Add(new PicInfo {fileName = "foo.bar", hashValue = new byte[] {1, 2, 3}});

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, pi);
            var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Sizes:

- `BinaryFormatter`: 488 bytes
- `XmlSerializer`: 251 bytes
- protobuf-net: 16 bytes

Comment: hi, it should not be an xml file, just a txt file. btw, can u explain why not the binaryformatter?

Comment: @Yustme very few serializers are going to write "just a txt file" - they will be formatted; perhaps bespoke binary, perhaps xml, perhaps json - but never "just a txt file" (unless you count xml or json as "just text"). Re `BinaryFormatter`: many reasons; it has a habit of being version intolerant, it is not cross-platform (for example, useless even on Silverlight), it is slow, and it has overweight output. Even invisible changes like making something an automatically implemented property will break it. Oh, and it tends to suck in unwanted objects via events.

Comment: i see. i got one more question, can i deserialize this again?

Comment: @Yustme absolutely! (btw, you can trivially replace the `MemoryStream` here with a `FileStream` if you are writing to disk). With `MemoryStream` just set the `.Position` back to 0. With a `FileStream` you would just `File.OpenRead(path)` to get the stream.