# Saving a list between applications in the .NET property settings

Tags: c#, list

I have a simple list, like this:

```
    fruitList = new FruitList();

    Apple fruit1 = new Apple("red", "small");
    Banana fruit2 = new Banana("yellow", "big");
    fruitList.AddFruit(fruit1);
    fruitList.AddFruit(fruit2);
```

My program displays this in a Textbox:

```
    textbox.Text = fruitList.DescribeCurrentFruit()
```

+

```
public string DescribeCurrentFruit()
{
    string description;

    if (fruitStock.Count > 0)
    {
        description = fruitStock[fruitCurrentlyDisplayed].Description();
    }
    else
    {
        description = "No Fruits in stock";
    }
    return description;
}
```

Currently, the List's two current objects/items (fruit1, fruit2) are automatically loaded as they are a part of my Window Form's load_event. However, if they're not a part of the load_event, or if I want to add more items/objects to the list at runtime, then permanently save them, how can I do so?

Well, I can do so by saving items in the project's property settings. (Serialization is an alternative option, but far too complex for me, and I want the simplest solution.) How do I go about this? Is there any sample code? I understand I first need to add items into my properties, but struggle even at this step.

Comment: What does "between applications" mean?  IMO, serialization of complex types is much easier than struggling with properties (which serializes them).  No idea what a `fruitList` is but it doesnt look like your fruits provide any clue as to the fruit type

Comment: Hi. Oops. I should have wrote "between sessions." In other words, so it is permanently saved. Serialization seemed so complex; perhaps I've dug myself into the wrong hole. How could I seralize this example fruit list?

Comment: The post you deleted had a link with the steps to serialize 3 different ways from someone who is an expert in it.  2-3 lines of code to save an entire collection is nothing.  If you are adverse to learning you ought to change your major/profession/hobby.

Comment: Hi @Plutonix. I apologize profusely; I didn't and still don't see the "link with the steps to serialize 3 different ways," only your reply as it stands. I'm very much welcoming learning. Best regards.

Comment: Your **[last (deleted) post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858661/c-sharp-simplest-way-to-permanently-save-load-a-list-systems-collections-gen)** (thats a link) was closed as a dupe to another which asked about serialization. *Dat be how dey do*  The thing at the top is **[another link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7964280/1070452)** (thats also a link) to a full throated answer covering serialzation.  Its a bit older so it doesnt cover JSON.  Finally, it is not too late to read [ask] and take the [tour]